# how to use soap response and get the xml values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body><GetXmlDocumentResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
       <GetXmlDocumentResult>
         <SNR_JO_POST xmlns=""> 
          <Sectors>   
           <LawyerName> abc</LawyerName>
            <ID>{B263A7B1-D766-4308-B486-C63BE66F4D74}</ID> 
           <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>  
           </Sectors>  
        </SNR_JO_POST>
      </GetXmlDocumentResult>
    </GetXmlDocumentResponse>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

the above is soap response , I want to get values of  LawyerName , ID and Email from the response .
How could i use this response in my c# code .

Comment: See ["How to Consume a Web Service"](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq To Xml for this

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var sectors = xDoc.Descendants("Sectors").FirstOrDefault();

var lawyerName = (string)sectors.Element("LawyerName");
var id = (string)sectors.Element("ID");
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't get you. What is wrong with it. I didn't know using *WebReference/ServiceReference* is a must...

Comment: He's processing SOAP. Why should he re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @JohnSaunders if he used a tool that creates a proxy, most probably he wouldn't see anywhere this soap response. And in the context of the question this is all i can do. Would you be  happy if I deleted this answer?

Comment: I'm happy either way. It's up to you.